# Get Same value once in SQL server Group by.

Tags: sql-server

I want to write group by query where i want same value only once is it possible?

My Query

```
SELECT NAME, SUM(SALARY) FROM CUSTOMERS GROUP BY NAME;
```

Output:

```
+----+----------+-----+-----------+----------+
| ID | NAME     | AGE | ADDRESS   | SALARY   |
+----+----------+-----+-----------+----------+
|  1 | Ramesh   |  32 | Ahmedabad |  2000.00 |
|  2 | Ramesh   |  25 | Delhi     |  1500.00 |
|  3 | kaushik  |  23 | Kota      |  2000.00 |
|  4 | kaushik  |  25 | Mumbai    |  6500.00 |
|  5 | Hardik   |  27 | Bhopal    |  8500.00 |
|  6 | Hardik   |  22 | MP        |  4500.00 |
|  7 | Hardik   |  24 | Indore    | 10000.00 |
+----+----------+-----+-----------+----------+
```

Expected output:

```
+----+----------+-----+-----------+----------+
| ID | NAME     | AGE | ADDRESS   | SALARY   |
+----+----------+-----+-----------+----------+
|  1 | Ramesh   |  32 | Ahmedabad |  2000.00 |
|  2 |          |  25 | Delhi     |  1500.00 |
|  3 | kaushik  |  23 | Kota      |  2000.00 |
|  4 |          |  25 | Mumbai    |  6500.00 |
|  5 | Hardik   |  27 | Bhopal    |  8500.00 |
|  6 |          |  22 | MP        |  4500.00 |
|  7 |          |  24 | Indore    | 10000.00 |
+----+----------+-----+-----------+----------+
```

Comment: your query can't give you the output you posted

Comment: That output is only useful in a UI so thats the layer in which to format it.

Comment: Your result set is not even a result of group by Name clause. How can you have Age, Address, Id without some kind of aggregation or max min?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few things first, if it is for UI, it is generally a good practice to manipulate data in the UI to appear the way you want.

Also, your result set is not even a result of `group by Name` clause. How can you have `Age, Address, Id` without some kind of `aggregation` or `max min`?

Anyway, if you want to have it the way you have shown in your question, one way to achieve would be:

```
CREATE TABLE #myTable
    (Id INT, FullName VARCHAR(200) NULL, age INT, salary DECIMAL);
INSERT INTO #myTable (Id,  FullName, age, salary)
VALUES (1, 'anc', 5, 1500),
    (2, 'anc', 15, 1000),
    (3, 'defc', 25, 12000),
    (4, 'defc', 45, 15000);

--mark with row_number and load into a temp table
SELECT mt.Id,
       mt.FullName,
       mt.age,
       mt.salary,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY mt.FullName ORDER BY mt.age) AS RowNum
INTO   #t1
FROM   #myTable AS mt;

-- update any non-first row
UPDATE t
SET    t.FullName = NULL
FROM   #t1 AS t
WHERE  t.RowNum != 1;

--select from tempTable
SELECT t.Id,
       t.FullName,
       t.age,
       t.salary
FROM   #t1 AS t;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use row_number as below:

```
Select Id, Case when (row_number() over (partition by Name order by Id) = 1) then [Name] else NULL end as [Name], Age, Address, Salary
   from yourtable
```

Answer (score 0):

This is actually really easy - SQL Server supports `LAG`, which accesses the previous row.  So, you just need to say "When the last row's name is the same as this row's name, leave name blank - otherwise, use the name":

```
SELECT  CASE WHEN LAG(Name) OVER(ORDER BY ID) = Name THEN '' ELSE Name END AS [Name],
        Age, 
        Address, 
        SUM(SALARY) AS [Salary]
FROM Customers
GROUP BY Name, Age, Address
```

Also, as you can see, you need to include all columns that are not aggregate functions in your `GROUP BY` clause - so you need to add `Age` and `Address`